# Kusto how to use comparison operator with timespan

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to write a query to see results that are over 15 days old.  I have this code where I am getting the avg_duration in the timespan format (15.04:01:02).  I want to now filter based off of avg_duration to only return results over 15 days old.

```
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ResourceId, RecommendationId, Severity
| order by RecommendationId asc, TimeGenerated asc
| extend duration = iff(RecommendationId == prev(RecommendationId), TimeGenerated - prev(TimeGenerated), 0s)
| summarize avg(duration) by ResourceId, RecommendationId, Severity
| where avg_duration >= "15.0:0:0"
```

When I run this in log Analytics I get the error "Cannot compare values of types timespan and long. Try adding explicit casts". Any ideas how I can filter timespan?

Comment: Hi @sspider3, please accept the answer below if it helps. Thanks. (See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) for more info on why and how to do it). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

`| where avg_duration >= "15.0:0:0"`

you should write

`| where avg_duration >= 15d` // note that `15d` stands for 15 days

See more details on how to write timespan literals [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/timespan).

Comment: That did the trick, I think I tried nearly everything but that, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @sspider3: please mark this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If by trying the proposed solution you are also facing `The operator '>' is not defined for the operand types datetime and timespan.(KS106)` when trying to apply arithmetic operators directly on your datetime field,

here is an alternative:

```
yourDateSource
| where yourDateTimeColumn > now(-1h)
```

The snippet above will return records from the last hour only.